# Remove “local or remote notifications” from notification center

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

I need to clear all notifications from my notification centre.I tried to `cancellAllLocalNotification` and `UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0` but its not working.i am using swift 4 and xcode 10.1 and ios 12.Anyone can help me..

Answer (score 9):

`cancellAllLocalNotification` is deprecated from iOS 10. from [appledoc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622990-cancelalllocalnotifications)

> Deprecated
>
> Use the UNUserNotificationCenter class to schedule local notifications instead.

Use

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllDeliveredNotifications() // For removing all delivered notification
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests() // For removing all pending notifications which are not delivered yet but scheduled.
```

From [Delivered Removal appledoc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter/1649502-removealldeliverednotifications)

> Use this method to remove all of your app’s delivered notifications from Notification Center. The method executes asynchronously, returning immediately and removing the identifiers on a background thread. This method does not affect any notification requests that are scheduled, but have not yet been delivered.

From [Pending Removal appledoc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter/1649509-removeallpendingnotificationrequ)

> This method executes asynchronously, removing all pending notification requests on a secondary thread.

Comment: I have already tried these ,but doesn't work,is any bug in ios 12?

Comment: Please share the code, from where exactly you are calling these methods ?

Comment: func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        print("payload",payload.dictionaryPayload)
{
 let state = UIApplication.shared.applicationState
        if state == .background  || state == .inactive{

         startTimer()
}
}

Comment: when i get a incoming push i trigger a timer for repeating local notifications for showing calling alert.

Comment: func startTimer() {
        timer2 = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 7, target: self, selector: (#selector(updateTimer2)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
 }

Comment: After 30s i need to invalidate the timer and remove the current notification in notification drawer.

Comment: please put those into the answer.

Comment: @RatulSharker into the *answer*?

Comment: -_- My bad, i meant “into the question”.